# Why does array.push() seem to push infinite times?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following javascript code,

```
>> a = [1, 2]
  Array [ 1, 2 ]

>> a.push(a) 
  Array [ 1, 2, Array[3] ]
```

On expanding the array, `a`, we get an array with infinite depth. (as viewed on the firefox developer console)

```
Array[3]
| 0: 1
| 1: 2
  2: Array[3]
  | 0: 1
  | 1: 2
  | 2: Array[3]
    | 0: 1
    | 1: 2
    | 2: Array[3]
    ....
```

[1] Why is a getting appended more than once?
[2] At what depth does it stop?

Comment: circular reference might explain this.

Comment: To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just pushed once. While the array is referencing itself ([circular refernce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference)), you see more than one inserted arrays. The display is dependent of the browser.

If you try to get a [JSON](http://json.org/) string, then [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) breaks with an error

> ```
> Circular reference in value argument not supported
> ```

```js
var a = [1, 2]
console.log(a);

a.push(a);
console.log(a);
JSON.stringify(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: SO neatly resolves the references, and shows them enclosing in `**`. +1 :)

Comment: but with a reference to the outer array and a third element in the inner array, the array itself., like `[1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, [1, 2, ...]]]]` but in reality it stores just `[1, 2, reference to array]`.

Comment: Does this work similar to how python stores range? It doesn't store the whole array, but computes it when required.

Comment: @TheChetan, sorry, i have no idea of python.

Answer (score 1):

It's not getting pushed an infinite number of times. It's a matter of how Firefox Developer Console **presents** the element. Expanding the array and clicking on it again, under itself, will always show you how the array looks like. So you can expand it and click it an infinite number of times, but still, it's there **only once**.

Answer (score 1):

You've created a circular reference.

When you push the array onto itself, the last element in the array becomes a reference to the entire array -- including that last element. So the last element in that last element is also a reference to the entire array, and so on.

It's infinite in the same sense that a circle is infinite, and "appends more than once" only in the same sense that if you go around a circle more than once you'll hit the same spot more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Because the javascript gives the reference to the 'a' variable, and not the actual object, so if you push the a to itself, you push the memory address what hold the object, and it creates a circular reference.

[1, 2, *reference to this object*]

Comment: What? Please explain a little more.

Comment: When you create the var a = [1, 2] object the 'a' holds the information of the memory address whats holds the object [1, 2] , when you say var b = a; you pass the reference, the memory address which contains the [1, 2] array object. so if you say b.push(3) it will add to that object an other item it will be [1, 2, 3] but the address doesn't changed so now a and b is equal [1, 2, 3] and if you cal a.push(a) it means you have an object which is [1, 2, *memory address itself*] so you can go deeper and deeper because it will be the same object

Comment: I know that. That is called a circular reference. Why don't you add that to your answer? Right now, it sounds a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pushing it only one time. It doesn't push the array elements, but the address of the array. Firefox console just tries to show what's in there, but ends up showing the same thing infinitely.

Not just Firefox, Chrome also does that.